# Laravel, Eloquent table relating to itself through pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have users class (table):

- id
- username

And relations table:

- user_id
- subscribed_by

Idea: each User can subscribe for each other user.
Last variant was (don't work):

```
/* class User extends Eloquent ... */ 
public function followers() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'rel_table')->withPivot('user_id');
}

public function following() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'rel_table')->withPivot('subscribed_by');
}
```

**Need help:** how to set up this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, an advice, you should rename the fields in your pivot table `follower_id` and `followed_id` (or something like that). That's more clear.

Then you have to define relations like that :

```
public function followers() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'rel_table', 'followed_id', 'follower_id');
}

public function following() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'rel_table', 'follower_id', 'followed_id');
}
```

The `withPivot` method is used to define other attributes on the relation than the two foreign keys.

Comment: Thank you, but how to use it? 
    Auth::user()->followers() // returns NULL;
    Auth::user()->following() // returns NULL;

Comment: Without more explanation about your error, I can't help you... You could read the doc : http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many.

Comment: In your answer there is no returns

Comment: You should receive an instance of `BelongsToMany`... I can't imagine why you get a null value. Are you sure you receive that ? Have you check with a `var_dump` ?

Comment: Everything is OK. And yes there was NULL, because I copied your code.  **Your code was without RETURN $this->...*